# Is there a way to display multi-line string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, alertify

I have a function which receives a single line string and displays it without a problem using an alert pop up from alertify JS but when its a multi-line string it gives an error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` . Below is my function:

```
<script>
function changes(changes) {

    alertify.confirm(changes,
        function () {
        }).setHeader('Document Changes');
}
```

The changes is the string am receiving and am displaying it in an alert box. Below is where am getting the changes from. I am getting this string from an object and passing it to my function

```
                {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<button onclick="changes(\'' + full.changes + '\')" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Changes</button>';
                }
            }
```

When i click this button it does not send the multi-line string to my function but when its a single line string it works without a problem

The sample text which brings the error is like below:

**added footer**

**added heder**

**added content**

Below is a fiddle which i have replicated the error
[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pistone45/f4dwby3p/1/)

Comment: can you provide a sample of `changes` string that trigger the error?

Comment: added footer /
added heder /
added content/ The slashes is the beginning of the new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the problem was multi lines strings, you can use the back ticks ` to print the multi line strings in javascript

```js
alert(`this is \n multi line \n string`)
```

and in your case would be:

```
alertify.confirm(`${changes}`,....
```

Comment: I traced the root of the problem. It is coming from where am receiving the changes string and from there it cant process the string and pass it on. Let me edit my question

Comment: `alertify.confirm(\`${changes}\`` - useless template
 use just `alertify.confirm(changes`

Comment: @zb' the usage of `alertify.confirm(changes` was the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the backticks, Luke.

```js
let changes =`
This is a 
multiline
alert
message
`;

alert(changes);
```